# Is there any possibility to match two words in the character, when these two words are surrounded by other words?

Tags: r, regex, text, gsub, stringr

I was trying to match two words from the text file together. Specifically, in the following link you can see biographies of the people: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1084869/0001437749-17-017820.txt  or https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1084869/000143774917017820/flws20171026b_def14a.htm

I.E. the links have the following : Larry Zarin, age 63, has been a director of the Company since March 2009. Mr. Zarin was Senior Vice President and Chief Marketing Officer for Express Scripts, a Fortune 25 company whose goal is to make the use of prescription drugs safer and more affordable, until his retirement in July 2013

So, I want to match the second name Zarin with the word Marketing and put this character of two words in one cell.

I created a table with the second name

```
NAME

Oliver       
Zarin        
McCann       
Hegarty
```

Here are the codes I used to clean the character vector.

```
a<-"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1084869/0001437749-17-017820.txt"
singleString <- paste(readLines(paste0(a)), collapse=" ")
singleString <-as.character(singleString)
b<-gsub("<[^>]+>", "",singleString)
a<-gsub('[0-9]+', '', b)
```

But afterwards I run different codes from the stringi package like stri_replace_all_regex . But every time I got the wrong results.

\bNAME?\s+(?:\w+\s+){0,30}marketing|Marketing\NAME\b

The code above helps to select for the range of words between the two NAMEs, so if the biography of another person starts, the biography of the preceded finishes.

The final output should look like this table

```
NAME       MARKETING

Oliver       1
Zarin        1
McCann       0
Hegarty      0
```

Comment: What does *Two words in the character* mean?

Comment: I.E. there will be characters "Zarin Marketing" "Oliver Marketing" " McCann none" "Hegarty none"